# How to make credentials available to shell script in jenkins

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, credentials

We have freestyle projects configured in Jenkins, running shell scripts as build steps. In some cases we need access to credentials for third-party services. We have solved this by providing the credentials as:

```
USER=theuser
PASS=thepass
```

in the project environment (`Prepare an environment for the run -> Properties Content`)

This is working fine, but it is a bad solution because:

- credentials are not stored securely
- they are visible to anybody having access to the project configuration
- they leak in the Jenkins console

We have researched a bit and found a [promising plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin), but we do not know how to make the credentials managed by the plugin available to our scripts, ideally as environment variables.

How can we access the credentials managed by the Jenkins plugin from a script?

Answer (score 6):

We are using this one:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin

Then you specify the environment-variables you want the passwords to have.

So if you specify something like this:
[image]

You can use `$PASSWORD` in your shell later on.

Answer (score 5):

```
withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: yourCredentialsId, usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']]) {
    // user name and password will be stored in USERNAME and PASSWORD envs
}
```

Comment: How would I do that from a bash script?

Comment: @Aurelien you link to the pipeline doc, the question is about freestyle projects.

Comment: Argh thanks @DanM., my mistake, I have deleted my comment.

Comment: I had to use this apparently similar expression:
`withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'my-id', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')])`